NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Environment Injector)[MsalService -> MsalService]: NullInjectorError: No provider for MsalService
why below error is throwing while integrating MSAL in my Angular app.
 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Environment Injector)[MsalService -> MsalService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for MsalService!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:1654:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3093:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3093:33)
    at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:15723:36)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:5730:39)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:5778:12)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:11050:19)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.AppComponent_Factory [as factory] (app.component.ts:12:26)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:5984:44)

package.json is having below dependencies:
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^3.0.16",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.13.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }

If need any more info, please let me know I will post it.
Need help in resolving this issue.

Have you added MsalModule.forRoot(msalConfig) to your app.module.ts file in imports?

It's not about packages, the error indicates that the service you are going to use is not properly implemented.

You will need to import MsalModule in the decorator of your app components imports array.
For example:
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    standalone: true,
    imports: [MsalModule]
})

